# Too strong assumption in the Uniqueness Theorem of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

In Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, there is the following result about Fourier transforms.

**The Uniqueness Theorem** *If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f}(t)=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.*

Isn't the assumption "*for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$*" unnecessarily too strong? I am pretty sure that we only need that $\hat{f}(t)=0$ *almost everywhere* to conclude that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere. But Rudin is a very smart guy, so I guess there is a good reason for saying "*for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$*".

**Note:** In Rudin, the Uniqueness Theorem is a corollary of the following theorem.

**The Inversion Theorem** *If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and if
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}dt\qquad(x\in\mathbb{R}),$$
then $g\in C_0$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere.*

Comment: If I remember correctly, all you need is $f \in L^1$ to have $\hat{f} \in C^0$. Then if $f \in C^0$ is zero a.e. then it is zero everywhere.

Comment: @Ian You are right! Thank you, that solved the problem. This book is awesome. If anything doesn't look right when you read it, it's always because you're missing something... Rudin simply doesn't make mistake.

Comment: Well Rudin does occasionally make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian pointed out, the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is continuous. For continuous functions, being zero a.e. and being zero everywhere are equivalent; so it makes more sense to use the shorter version, without a.e.